# No MaterialLocalizations found error is occurring for TextFields

Tags: flutter, internationalization, textfield, intl

I need to add function a language selection function for my app. And it was done. The next problem is that the main language should be Russian. I do not need English right now. but `intl_en.arb` file is creating automatically. Hence I found another way. That is, it is possible to set the initial language with `Locale('ru')` inside MaterialApp or CupertinoApp. I am using CupertinoApp right now. The following error is occurring when I use the CupertinoApp.

```
 CupertinoApp(
              theme: theme,
              localizationsDelegates: [
                AppLocalizationDelegate(),
                DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
                DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              ],
              locale: Locale('ru'),
              supportedLocales: AppLocalizationDelegate().supportedLocales,
              onGenerateRoute: Application.router.generator,
              home: state.showLogin ? LanguageController() : HomeController(),
            ),
```

[image]

but that is working well with `Locale('en')`

[image]

I've found resources from some sites to solve the problem.
F.E : https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/text-field-material-localizations

but the result is still negative.

I think this problem is happening for only `TextField`. Because other texts are working.

Is there any other way?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried setting the locale with `localeListResolutionCallback`? 

   localeListResolutionCallback: (_,__) {
      return Locale('id', 'ID');
   },

If it does not work, you can try `easy_localization` package

Comment: @Pushpendra Thanks for your response.  Yes, I have tried with localeListResolutionCallback. The problem is just setting the initial language. I am using `intl`  package (with [Localizely](http://Localizely.com)). I think, no need to change the package